# Java - Set datetime17:30 if the current time is before 17:00

Tags: java, spring, datetime, if-statement, time

I'm trying to set a value of dispatch date for an email type.

So I want people to get these mails after 17:30, which is cool...

I have

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

If( "342856".equals(emailTemplateId))  {
        tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + "17:30:00");
        LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
        } 
else {
        tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(null);
        LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
        }
```

Now, I can't send an email to go out at 17:30 if I send it after 17:30... so I need to say..

```
  If( "342856".equals(emailTemplateId))  AND **thecurrenttimetoday <= 17:00:00** { 
      tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + "17:30:00"); 
      LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
        } 
else {
        tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(null);
        LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
        }
```

i'm really really new to java, and not at all sure how to do this... any ideas?

Really appreciate and help with this, it's been melting my little brain all morning!

Comment: Are you using a scheduler?

Comment: Yes, the front end application takes this in a soap UI request and processes the message, it sends the email at the ScheduledDate if it's populated, but sends it immediately if it's not, if the ScheduledDate is populated, but the time is in the past, it will hang there, and won't go out, so i'd like to prevent this from happening, and send anything 30 minutes before 17:30 out immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do this. please elaborate if I missed something.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String  emailTemplateId = ""; //some value
    Calendar  boundaryTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    boundaryTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
    boundaryTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
    boundaryTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    boundaryTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);


    if( "342856".equals(emailTemplateId) && cal.getTime().before(boundaryTime.getTime()))  {
        tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(boundaryTime.getTime());
            LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
     }
    else {
        tmp_disp.setScheduledDate(null);
        LOGGER.debug(">>> ScheduledDate: " + tmp_disp.getScheduledDate());
```

Comment: Thank you Arno, I think I can use this to get what I need!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in your code before come to your issue.

```
If  (emailTemplateId = "342856") // very bad way of checking String equility
```

Use

```
If( "342856".equals(emailTemplateId))
```

Comment: Ah cool, this definitely makes sense to me thanks for the tip, I'll edit the post with this.

Comment: It wasn't even comparison, but assignment :)

Comment: Ah, right, so the "=" assigned the emailTemplateId to "342856", to check if the preassigned emailTemplateId is the same as this value I need to call the value and use if("somevalue".equals(someVariable)) ... fair enough, i'm really new to this, apologies if It looks like I haven't tried, I swear I have!